# Not able to click items in Unity build using C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created an Inventory System using Unity and C# script, I followed Kryzarel's tutorial on Youtube to make the Inventory System. I'm not able to click the items in build. I tried rechecking the code with Kryzarel's code and im not able to find what is going wrong. The following are the classes where Events have been assigned.

`

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using CharacterStats;

    public class Character : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public CharacterStat Strength;
        public CharacterStat Agility;
        public CharacterStat Intelligence;
        public CharacterStat Defence;
        public CharacterStat Damage; 

        [SerializeField] Inventory inventory;
        [SerializeField] EquipmentPanel equipmentPanel;
        [SerializeField] StatPanel statPanel;
        [SerializeField] Image draggableItem;

        private ItemSlot draggedSlot;

        private void Awake()
        {
            statPanel.SetStats(Strength, Agility, Intelligence, Defence,Damage);
            statPanel.UpdateStatValues();


            inventory.OnRightClickEvent += Equip;
            equipmentPanel.OnRightClickEvent += Unequip;
            inventory.OnBeginDragEvent += BeginDrag;
            equipmentPanel.OnBeginDragEvent += BeginDrag;

            inventory.OnEndDragEvent += EndDrag;
            equipmentPanel.OnEndDragEvent += EndDrag;

            inventory.OnDragEvent += Drag;
            equipmentPanel.OnDragEvent += Drag;

            inventory.OnDropEvent += Drop;
            equipmentPanel.OnDropEvent += Drop;

       }



   }`

`
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] List<Item> startingItems;
    [SerializeField] Transform itemsParent;
    [SerializeField] ItemSlot[] itemSlots;

    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnRightClickEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnPointerEnterEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnPointerExitEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnBeginDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnEndDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnDropEvent;


    private void Start()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < itemSlots.Length; i++)
        {
            itemSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent += OnRightClickEvent;
            itemSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent += OnPointerEnterEvent;
            itemSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent += OnPointerExitEvent;
            itemSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent += OnBeginDragEvent;
            itemSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent += OnEndDragEvent;
            itemSlots[i].OnDragEvent += OnDragEvent;
            itemSlots[i].OnDropEvent += OnDropEvent;
        }
        SetStartingItems();
    }`


`
public class EquipmentPanel : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform equipmentSlotsParent;
    [SerializeField] EquipmentSlot[] equipmentSlots;

    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnRightClickEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnPointerEnterEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnPointerExitEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnBeginDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnEndDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnDragEvent;
    public event Action<ItemSlot> OnDropEvent;


    public void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < equipmentSlots.Length; i++)
        {
            equipmentSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent += OnRightClickEvent;
            equipmentSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent += OnPointerEnterEvent;
            equipmentSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent += OnPointerExitEvent;
            equipmentSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent += OnBeginDragEvent;
            equipmentSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent += OnEndDragEvent;
            equipmentSlots[i].OnDragEvent += OnDragEvent;
            equipmentSlots[i].OnDropEvent += OnDropEvent;
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Did you wire button clicks in the scene? Do you have `EventSystem` in your scene?

Comment: @Johnny I did use EventSystem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ItemSlot inside the Inventory? it possibly function overlapping.

you could see that

```
//the inventory event handler
inventory.OnRightClickEvent += Equip;
inventory.OnBeginDragEvent += BeginDrag;
inventory.OnEndDragEvent += EndDrag;
inventory.OnDragEvent += Drag;
inventory.OnDropEvent += Drop;

//the itemslot event handler
for(int i=0; i < itemSlots.Length; i++)
    {
        itemSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent += OnRightClickEvent;
        itemSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent += OnPointerEnterEvent;
        itemSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent += OnPointerExitEvent;
        itemSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent += OnBeginDragEvent;
        itemSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent += OnEndDragEvent;
        itemSlots[i].OnDragEvent += OnDragEvent;
        itemSlots[i].OnDropEvent += OnDropEvent;
    }
```

this two event handler could be overlapped, so when you click the itemslot, it could be the inventory even handler that processed